# youtube_dl - Cannot prevent error logs from posting

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

How do I prevent the printing of `youtube_dl` error logs?

```
[tls @ 0x5599ebcc8d00] Error in the pull function.
[https @ 0x5599ebcc65c0] Will reconnect at 98304 in 0 second(s), error=Input/output error.
[tls @ 0x5599ebff9cc0] Error in the pull function.
[https @ 0x5599ebcc65c0] Will reconnect at 2523120 in 0 second(s), error=Input/output error.
[tls @ 0x55e262434d00] Error in the pull function.
[https @ 0x55e2624325c0] Will reconnect at 131072 in 0 second(s), error=Input/output error.
[tls @ 0x556d70c28d00] Error in the pull function.
[https @ 0x556d70c265c0] Will reconnect at 131072 in 0 second(s), error=Input/output error.
[tls @ 0x5609e85e4d00] Error in the pull function.
[https @ 0x5609e85e25c0] Will reconnect at 131072 in 0 second(s), error=Input/output error.
[tls @ 0x555649486d00] Error in the pull function.
[https @ 0x5556494845c0] Will reconnect at 131072 in 0 second(s), error=Input/output error.
[tls @ 0x5647e561dd00] Error in the pull function.
```

I have tried `'ignoreerrors': True` but it doesn't work.

```
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

YT_OPTIONS = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'extractaudio': True,
    'audioformat': 'mp3',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': True,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0',
}
```

I'm using [this bot](https://gist.github.com/vbe0201/ade9b80f2d3b64643d854938d40a0a2d)

Comment: Where are you using `YT_OPTIONS`?

Comment: if possible then share the code that you tried so far

Comment: @Benjin I'm using [this bot](https://gist.github.com/vbe0201/ade9b80f2d3b64643d854938d40a0a2d)

Comment: @Sabil I'm using [this bot](https://gist.github.com/vbe0201/ade9b80f2d3b64643d854938d40a0a2d)

Answer (score 3):

That is not a error produced by `youtube_dl` it is from ffmpeg cause your session has expired. It occurs for everyone who try to stream audio without downloading the video from YouTube.

Either download the video by removing audio options in your YouTube_dl options or add this to your ffmpeg options.

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/671

```py
'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5'
```

Before copying a open-sourced code remember to check the issues, limitations, etc. given by them.

Comment: I have given these option too

Answer (score 2):

[The `quiet` keyword is what you want](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L151), suppressing messages to standard output.

Make sure you're actually applying the options when calling youtube_dl.

```py
YT_OPTIONS = {
    ...
    'quiet': True,
    ...
}

youtube_dl_manager = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YT_OPTIONS)
```

Comment: I've already added `'quiet': True` it doesn't work

Comment: Then your problem isn't the options, its you not applying those options. You need to show the rest of the code.

Comment: I'm using [this bot](https://gist.github.com/vbe0201/ade9b80f2d3b64643d854938d40a0a2d)

Answer (score 2):

One way to prevent errors from printing is to provide a [`logger`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/a8035827177d6b59aca03bd717acb6a9bdd75ada/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L178) that is disabled like in [this example](https://github.com/voxel51/fiftyone/blob/3b8cb1593ba34a6c5004f8b79069c5cc707ad9a5/fiftyone/utils/youtubedl.py#L151-L156).

```py
import logging
import youtube_dl

url = "..."

ytdl_logger = logging.getLogger("ytdl-ignore")
ytdl_logger.disabled = True
ydl_opts = {
    "logger": ytdl_logger,
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
```

The issues with the other parameters were:

- [`quiet`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/a8035827177d6b59aca03bd717acb6a9bdd75ada/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L151) does not prevent error messages from being logged
- [`ignoreerrors`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/a8035827177d6b59aca03bd717acb6a9bdd75ada/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L168) will prevent the errors from being raised (which I still wanted to catch, just not print)

Comment: wait you created `ytdl`?

Comment: No, I just ran into the same issue recently while working on a wrapper to download computer vision datasets with `ytdl`